# How do I search key, value pairs from a dictionary where I only know a partial string of the value?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have a dictionary where I have values associated with each key as such:

```
mail_info={'2367': ['Payment Claim'], '2610': ['Managing Contractor Advice '], '2453': ['Variations'], '3453': ['Trade Package Variation Recommendation'], '654': ['Response to Variation']......}
```

I would like to extract all key, value pairs where the word 'Variation' or 'Variations' is a part of the string.

I tried the following command:

```
[(k, v) for (k, v) in mail_info.items() if 'Variations' in v]
```

But that only returns exact matches.

Can someone please suggest a correct way to do this? Perhaps using regex (although not necessary)?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. My expected output is another dictionary with k,v pairs as the results.

Comment: Your dictionary values aren't strings; they are _lists_ of strings.  If you want "normal" substring matching, make the values plain strings instead of lists of single strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not the most elegant solution, but should work for you

```
mail_info={'2367': ['Payment Claim'],
           '2610': ['Managing Contractor Advice '],
           '2453': ['Variations'],
           '3453': ['Trade Package Variation Recommendation'],
           '654': ['Response to Variation']
           }


new_d = {key:mail_info[key] for key in mail_info if 'Variation' in mail_info[key][0]}

print(new_d)
```

Comment: This works partially. I still do not get the values with the word 'Variations' in it.

Comment: @ Alex Jadczak Actually I double checked, this works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: @snakepain good, glad it works.  I was scratching my head for a second there.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest converting those lists into strings and then checking for the phrase in the resulting string. Something like:

```
new_dict = {}

for key in mail_info:
    string = ''.join(mail_info[key])
    if 'Variation' in string:
        new_dict[key] = string
```